# How to close NamedPipeClientStream?

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I can't close my WPF application because the NamedPipeClientStream endlessly runs. I tried using `ConnectAsync`, I tried disposing it, but no matter what it prevents the process from ending.

I use the pipe to listen for messages so it needs to run until the application quits.

This is my current attempt:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    namedPipeClient = new(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppGUID"]!);
    Thread PipeThread = new(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                PipeReceive();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException) { break; }
        }
    });
    PipeThread.Start();
}

// Called when window is closed
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    namedPipeClient.Close();
    namedPipeClient.Dispose();

    base.OnClosed(e);
}


private void PipeReceive()
{
    namedPipeClient.Connect(1000);
    if (namedPipeClient.IsConnected)
    {
        // Retrieve message
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops, turns out the reason was because this is a WPF application and I had enabled `Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown`

Comment: That Thread should be a Background Thread (`PipeThread.IsBackground = true;`).

Comment: @fabraham Can you write your answer as an actual answer under the question, and accept it? This way, others visiting the question can discover it more easily, and you get bonus answer karma in return :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue didn't have anything to do with named pipes. I was under the impression it did because in Visual Studio's "Running Tasks" it showed a reference to the named pipe methods and listed them as active.

The real issue was the I had changed the application `ShutdownMode` to `OnExplicitShutdown` so even after the main window was closed the application would remain running unless the `Shutdown()` method is called. My fix was to override the `OnClosed` event.

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);

    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```